# Clean-up specific cache entry in Firefox

Tags: firefox, redirection, browser-cache

There is a website that occasionally stupidly redirects with HTTP Status 301 (“Moved Permanently”) its login page to a “maintenance” page.

I tried to visit this page while the redirection was effective, so Firefox cached it. Now, the redirection is not effective anymore, but, when I want to visit the login page, Firefox sees the cached redirection and immediately shows me the “maintenance” page…

I checked the `about:cache` page and could check that the redirection was indeed cached. I hoped there would be a button to remove that cache entry, but did not find it.

I know I can clean the whole cached web content, but that sounds overkill.

I also know I can use the “forget about this site” feature from the history, but it would also forget the remembered credentials, which is somewhat troublesome.

So is there I can purge this specific cache entry?

(No need to tell me that the webmaster is a moron who does not understand the difference between temporary and permanent redirects, I know…)

Answer (score 2):

Found this reference that I believe may help. Scroll to middle where it goes over the steps for FireFox specifically.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/clear-cache-cookies-specific-website

Basically: 
'Open your Mozilla Firefox web browser and then open its Options. Select Privacy & Security next. Here under Cookies and Site Data press the Manage Data button to open the following panel.' Here you'll be able to remove cookies and data for specific domains.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it does not seem to help. The cached pages (and cached redirections) are not cookies or site data. Thanks anyway for your help.